# Align text to left and right in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook in which I need to align text (from cells) to the left and the to the right. I have this so far but I don't know how to proceed.

```
Sub M()

ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = ActiveSheet.Range("A1") & " " & 
ActiveSheet.Range("B1")

End Sub
```

I want to know in general how to override the alignment for text in each part of the header but in this instance, I need to have text aligned to the left in both the right and left headers.

Comment: I assume your two lines of posted code (`ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = ActiveSheet.Range("A1") & " " &` and `ActiveSheet.Range("B1")`) are actually only one line of code in your program.  If not, it won't compile.

Comment: "align text (from cells) to the left and the to the right" - do you mean justify?  If Yes, that's not an option in Excel.

Comment: @TimWilliams Excel has "Distributed" as one of the **cell** formatting options.  Doubt if it can be used in headings though.

Comment: @TimWilliams It also has "Justify" as one of the **cell** formatting options, but that (of course) only applies for multi-line cell contents.  Again, I doubt if it can be used in headings in any way.

Comment: @YowE3K - thanks that will teach me not to comment without checking first

Comment: @TimWilliams If the question is specifically about **headers** then your comment is probably quite accurate when referring to just headers.  (Just isn't so accurate these days when interpreted in a generic "Excel doesn't handle this" sense.  And, FWIW, I didn't expect it to handle "Justify" or "Distributed" in cells either. :D)

Comment: I want to know in general how to override the alignment for text in each part of the header but in this instance, I need to have text aligned to the left in both the right and left headers.

Comment: @KevinLópez See my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am interpreting your question as "I want to have one cell's value as the left part of my header, and another cell's value as the right part of my header".

If so, you probably want:

```
Sub M()
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That is what I meant, sorry! What you said worked but I can't change the horizontal alignment in each part of the header, any way to do that?

Comment: @KevinLópez The `LeftHeader` should be left-aligned, and the `RightHeader` should be right-aligned.  What do you want it to be?  (The only things I can think of might be (a) you want the two "parts" to be centred over the two halves of the page, or (b) you want the left header right-aligned, and the right header left-aligned, effectively creating a center header which isn't actually centred.  Option (b) is possibly "do-able", but I doubt if option (a) is.)

Comment: I want to know in general how to override the alignment for text in each part of the header but in this instance, I need to have text aligned to the left in both the right and left headers.

Comment: @KevinLópez The left-aligned left header is obviously no issue.  A left-aligned right header is harder - all I could suggest for that would be to use `.CenterHeader = Space(Len(ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value)) & ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value`, which won't be 100% correct with a proportional font, but would be (I think) with a fixed-width font.

Answer (score 4):

To do this in Excel, select the section of cells needed to align. Then, type <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for left, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for center, and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for right.

However, based on your question it seems like you want to do this in VBA instead of Excel. If that is the case, do this instead:

`Range(myRange).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight` for right, and
`Range(myRange).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft` for left, where myRange is the range of cells.

Answer (score 3):

The HorizontalAlignment property of the Range should be what you're looking for. xlLeft or xlRight are values to align left or right.

```
Range.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
```

or

```
Range.HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
```

E.G.

```
Sub M()

ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = ActiveSheet.Range("A1") & " " & 
ActiveSheet.Range("B1").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight

End Sub
```

would align the B1 cell to the right.

Answer (score 1):

I found you can use .api to center / left / right align.

- Set the value of the HorizontalAlignment property of the cell to:

  - Center-aligned, we’d set HorizontalValue to -4108;
  - Right-aligned, we’d set HorizontalValue to -4152;
  - Left-aligned, we’d set HorizontalValue to -4131;

What it would look like:

```
import xlwings as xw
sht = xw.sheets.active
sht.range(f'$A1:$C5').api.HorizontalAlignment = -4131
```

Comment: This works for me! Can you pls explain where you found this info?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Range("A1").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft` or `... = xlRight`

Of course, adjust the range(s) as necessary.